# What are some fragmentation issues you've encountered while developing Android apps?

Tags: android

There seems to be so much coverage in the press about dealing with Android fragmentation issues, but I couldn't find anything concrete from developers on SO. So what were some fragmentation issues you've encountered while developing for Android?

I've been developing for Android 2.1+ devices mostly, and haven't yet encountered any issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Varying screen resolutions
- Varying display sizes
- On board memory sizes differ greatly and go from minuscule (32mb) to "accepted standard" (16-32 gb)
- Many different versions "in the wild" with different capabilities
- Device manufacturers can create skins for the phone and change basic functionality and colors
- Cell phone carriers can further customize the experience and block certain abilities (e.g. installing form "unknown sources")
- The seemingly random combination of all of the above

The "fragmentation" issue is that you, as a developer, have to test in many different combinations of devices and configurations to make sure your application runs satisfactorily in all of them. You also have to consider that your application layouts will be displayed in many different resolutions, so the end result might be pretty crappy in a tablet, for example.

In reality my guess is that you give up trying to support everything and try to get as much market as you can with as little extra development as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The latest thing I've run into is that some Motorola phones do not auto orient photos like HTC phones do. So you have read the EXIF data to orient the photos properly, but since I don't have an Moto phone its a little hard to test.
There are also some inconsistencies with the android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent on some phones.

Both of these issues have been discussed on StackOverflow.

For the most part these are not big deals. I like to equate it to CSS browser inconsistence. There are a few issues, but its nothing developers are not used to.

Answer (score 0):

The only real oddity i've experienced is the Secure.ANDROID_ID, which is supposed to be unique, but really isn't.  Some vendors and/or custom ROMs dont generate a unique one.  And then you just have to create a unique ID for the user.

Answer (score 0):

Multitouch has been officially supported since Android 2.0, but implementations vary tremendously across devices, and frequently do not follow the spec.